# Does opening a sqlite connection per query affect the performace? Is that mandatory for multi-threading support?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, sqlite

I’m planning to use the objective-c-sql-query builder from ziminji on an iPhone and iPad project. This library supports multi-threading, like I need. I’ve initially done my project using Core Data, but the performance is bad when the amount of data grows a lot. For example, when I have to delete everything (hundred-thousands of rows), it takes a long time, which makes sense due to the object-oriented layer. Accessing the database directly is a lot faster.

I looked at the library’s code and I noticed that every time I query the database, it opens a connection to the database. Isn’t this slow? Wouldn’t it be faster to keep the database connection opened while the app is active? Or would it be a problem to implement it like that with multi-threading support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Objective-C SQL Query Builder library for SQLite](https://github.com/ziminji/objective-c-sql-query-builder) offers three way to open a connection as noted on its [Wiki](https://github.com/ziminji/objective-c-sql-query-builder/wiki/Establishing-a-Database-Connection):

```
// (Alternative #1)
ZIMDbConnection *connection = [[ZIMDbConnectionPool sharedInstance] connection: @"live"];
NSArray *records = [connection query: @"SELECT * FROM Customer;"];

// (Alternative #2)
ZIMDbConnection *connection = [[ZIMDbConnection alloc] initWithDataSource: @"live"];
NSArray *records = [connection query: @"SELECT * FROM Customer;"];
[connection close];

// (Alternative #3)
NSArray *records = [ZIMDbConnection dataSource: @"live" query: @"SELECT * FROM Customer;"];
```

The first two alternatives allow for the connection to remain open.  In fact, that is the whole purpose of a database connection pool.  With the database connection pool, you do not have to worry about opening and closing the connection because the class manages this for you; whereas, the second alternative you manage the connection.  In the third alternative, this is just a quick way to open the connection, query, and then close the connection all in one line of code.

If you are going to utilize multi-threading, you will need to use either the first or second alternative.  If you chose the second alternative, create an instance variable in your class and open the connection, then start your threads.  Once all of your threads have finished running, close the connection...otherwise just leave it open.

Answer (score 0):

Opening a new connection on SQLite isn't anything like opening a new connection to a remote database. Keeping the connection open all the time would probably be faster (maybe at the cost of locking the database file), but it's not likely to account for significant performance problems. Even if opening the connection takes time, actually parsing the query and executing the command itself will take more time.

And yes, you should always keep your SQLite commands to a specific thread. The easiest way to enforce this is to serialize everything onto one thread with a custom created GCD dispatch queue (the global queues are parallel and risk running things concurrently).

Comment: I've changed the title to questions instead of the subject. @Jesper are you saying that it makes no sense to access the database from different threads?

Comment: Thanks. I am saying that it is actively harmful to access the SQLite database from different threads *concurrently*. Limit your access to one command running at a time. SQLite won't complain (much) if you run a query on thread A, then on thread B, then on thread C, but it will complain if you attempt to run queries at the same time on thread A and thread B, and if you don't specifically execute them on a thread or a queue, only luck prevents this. [See the SQLite FAQ for more](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6). Just pushing the database access to another thread is perfectly fine and allowed.

Comment: One more comment. [The FMDB SQLite library](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) was just updated with code (`FMDatabaseQueue`) that solves this.